# GUID variable for JPEG,BMP,PNG

Tags: c++, mfc, jpeg, guid, bmp

I want to store a image in JPEG format. I am using [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14075/High-speed-Charting-Control) for creating charts. Now I want to save the chart. A function name SaveAsImage() is provided by library which required GUID parameter.

Here is the code :

How should I initialize GUID for jpeg?

```
            TChartString title = m_ChartSeriesDetail[i].seriesTitle;
            m_ChartCtrl.Print(title, 0);
            CRect rect;
            GUID guid;
            m_ChartCtrl.SaveAsImage((TChartString)m_ChartName, rect, 32, guid);

 ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// //! 
 Saves the chart to an image file
     /**
    This function is not available for VC6 and earlier.
    @param strFilename
        The name of the file in which to save the image.
    @param rect
        The size of the image. If an empty rectangle is provided, the
        size of the chart on screen will be used (this results in an identical
        image as what is seen on the screen).
    @param nBPP
        The numbers of bits per pixel in the bitmap. Usually 4, 8, 16, 24, or 32. 
    @param guidFileType
        The file type to save the image as. See the CImage::Save in MSDN
        for more information.
**/
void SaveAsImage(const TChartString& strFilename, const CRect& rect, 
        int nBPP, REFGUID guidFileType= GUID_NULL);`
```

Comment: Your question is missing a *question*.

Comment: sorry ,how should i initialize GUID for jpeg??

Comment: Did you try to "See the CImage::Save in MSDN for more information"? That documentation tells you exactly what the possible parameters are.

Answer (score 1):

As documented in the code you posted, the missing information is documented in the documentation for [CImage::Save](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/52861e3d-bf7e-481f-a240-90e88f76c490.aspx#cimage__save):

> `guidFileType`
>   The file type to save the image as. Can be one of the following:
>
> - `ImageFormatBMP` An uncompressed bitmap image.
> - `ImageFormatPNG` A Portable Network Graphic (PNG) compressed image.
> - `ImageFormatJPEG` A JPEG compressed image.
> - `ImageFormatGIF` A GIF compressed image.
>
> Note: For a complete list of constants, see Image File Format Constants in the Windows SDK.

Here is a link to the complete list of [Image File Format Constants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534410.aspx).